# php для чего делают кучу классов исключений?

Tags: php

Не могу понять, для чего при выбрасывании исключения нужно передавать какой-то класс? 
Для чего все разрабатывают для каждого класса свой класс с исключением? В чем специфика?

Почему нельзя написать более-менее "универсальный" класс исключения, которое будет выводить соответствующую ошибку (что и где сломалось).

Нежели нужно создавать и называть классы исключений лишь для наглядности, чтобы понимать в каком классе ошибка и т.д.?

Comment: Чтобы по разному их обрабатывать в том числе.

Comment: Что значит обрабатывать? Например?

Comment: Например если упало исключение первого типа - то записать сообщение в лог, второго типа - оповестить кого-то емейлом.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/848727/%D0%A5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B-exception-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1/848757#848757